# error is [Errno 131] Connection reset by peer followed by error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: android, python, sockets, chat, socketserver

I am using a python chat room server [from this code](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/78535/python-chat-server) but I am having a issue in running with the client's exceptional behaviour, my server hangs and stops working when my Android client switches to another network and then switches back to chat server network.
first I get the error

```
error is [Errno 131] Connection reset by peer
```

and then

```
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I want to handle this in my Chat server code and keep it up running always either client connects or disconnects, 
the detailed exception is

```
---------------------------------------------
error is [Errno 131] Connection reset by peer
---------------------------------------------

Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.2.46', 43160)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
self.finish()
File "/home/rahulm/datagroup.py", line 242, in finish
self.roomcast('\n  %s has disconnected  *\n' % self)
 File "/home/rahulm//datagroup.py", line 341, in roomcast
listener.request.send(data)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
error is [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
----------------------------------------

Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.2.63', 40460)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
self.finish()
File "/mnt/usb/PirateBox/Shared/datagroup.py", line 242, in finish
self.roomcast('\n  %s has disconnected  *\n' % self)
File "/mnt/usb/PirateBox/Shared/datagroup.py", line 341, in roomcast
listener.request.send(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
----------------------------------------
```

Note:- I am running chat server in the embedded device So I cant use Twisted 
any help most appreciated.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Your socket connection was probably closed before `listener.request.send(data)` the file descriptor is the os handle system whenever you open a port the os opens it like an open file when you close it the file is cleared.

Comment: thanks Kobi K, So what can be the solution for this ? can you suggest any please ?

Comment: I would just debug my code to see if there is a closing action for the connection for either server or client, you can ratify  that this is your problem by commenting the final send at your `finish()` method

Comment: I commented this line 'self.request.close' in the finish() method but still not working can you please be more specific and help ?

Comment: It's really hard to say it without any code, if you can attach the relevant code it will be easier to check it.

Comment: My complete sample code is pasted here at  [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/5ffkpvSA) please see if you can make it out working anything from it.